# StreamInsight - How to consume published event stream on a different host

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to consume events that were published on a different host? To be more exactly: if I have two CEP servers running on different hosts how can I bind a query to an event producer that's running in a different CEP engine.
I would greatly appreciate some real examples, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StreamInsight team has just posted an update of [their samples on CodePlex](http://streaminsight.codeplex.com), including a WCF adapter and application. It is a very simple example, but it shows how to use WCF to stream events across the wire. You can use this as a starting point to connect two StreamInsight engines. Keep in mind that this might not be the best solution for very high data rates.

Comment: Thanks! The basic idea is to create an I/O adapter pair but, I'm wondering why doesn't provide the SI a solution for this. Or maybe I'm wrong, it provides. I'm just thinking about the query composition at run-time: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff518536.aspx. Can be used this one to stream events across the wire?

Comment: Dynamic query composition only works within one server process. StreamInsight doesn't package any adapters with its V1 - performant and robust adapters are beyond the possible scope at this point. The product team is publishing the separate samples on CodePlex as guidelines for various adapter designs.

Comment: @romans : i need a small clarification about streamInsight, I know by doc's that StreamInsight can handle multiple concurrent Events. But will the event producer be a separate function, for ex: I need to watch a folder for new Files becoz all my sensors il write readings every day in a new file in particular drive. So do i need to use FileSystemWatcher to watch these new files and then raising events which is consumed by StreamInsight. or Can streamInsight has something to do this... Can i avoid FileSystemWatcher by using StreamInsight?.